# jquery .find() to search for one of two different values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I am making it editable. On double click on a cell I make the cell editable and clicking outside I revert it with the updated value.

```
tableCells.dblclick(function() {
    cell=$(this)
    value=cell.text();
    editing=true;
    rowIndex = cell.parent().index('table tbody tr');
    tdIndex = cell.index('table tbody tr:eq('+rowIndex+') td');
    switch(tdIndex) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 9:
            cell.html('<input type="text" value="'+value+'">');
        break;
        case 3:
            cell.html('<select name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control"><option value="1">Uomo</option><option value="2">Donna</option></select>');
            break;
        case 4:
            let temp = value.split('/');
            value=temp[2]+'-'+temp[1]+'-'+temp[0];
            cell.html('<input type="date" value="'+value+'">');
        break;
    }
});
$(document).click(function(e) { //se clicco fuori dalla tabella
    if(editing){
        if (!tableCells.toArray().some(f => f.contains(e.target))) {
            let row = cell.parent('tr').data('row'); //la riga da aggiornare nel db
            updValue=cell.find('input').val();
            if(e.target.cellIndex==4){
                let temp=updValue.split('-');
                updValue=temp[2]+'/'+temp[1]+'/'+temp[0];
            }
            
            console.log(updValue);
            console.log('riga '+row);
            cell.html(updValue);
            editing = false;
        }

    }
})
```

this `updValue=cell.find('input').val();` works fine for the fields where I have an input. But in one situation I replace the cell with a select. How can I add the `select` situation to this code in the lightest way? I will always have only input or select only editing the table. In pseudocode I'd say `.find('input'||'select')`. I don't want to have to add a class or a name attribute but to keep searching for the tag type (input or select)

I have tried with `.find('input','select')` but i get undefined this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add classes to those inputs/selects and then `cell.find('.myInput')` or use this, assume you have `name` attribute `cell.find('[name]')`

Or else the solution is:  `cell.find('select, input')`

Comment: thanks but i am looking for a way to do it with the selector and not with a name or a class attribute

Comment: @LelioFaieta in that case, you try `cell.find('select, input')`

Comment: ok, this works. I was doing wrong with the quotes

Comment: @LelioFaieta please vote my answer or mark as answer if that works, thank you!

Comment: please edit the answer to reflect the correct answer (in comment)